# Unicode characters aren't displayed in browsers (both interface and pages)

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, unicode, browser

I noticed that Icecat won't show Unicode characters such as ツ correctly, even though my fonts seem to be configured correctly. I tried to investigate, and realized that in fact it not only fails to render them within pages, but if I paste the character into the address bar, search bar, find toolbar or elsewhere in the interface I also get the mojibake/box.

I then found out that the same issue exists for Brave and Chromium - box in pages, box in interface. However, the same character displays fine in other programs (I can even paste it), for instance in the Cinnamon start menu, the search box of the Font selector, terminal, text editor, calculator and so on. Basically the only place where the character ツ is *not* displayed correctly is within browsers. Funnily enough, even elinks displays the characters correctly, but Icecat, Brave and Chromium do not.

What's going on? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: ツ is a Japanese character, not unicode.